# Modify value attribute within HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I need a function to modify the value attribute in the input element when the user modifies it. I have a function that downloads the html into a text file. I want the file to accurately record the current value of the element, not what it was on load.

JS download function:

```
function saveActors() {
    let fileName = `page.txt`;
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    let target = document.getElementById('target');
    a.download = fileName;
    let content = new Blob([target.innerHTML], {type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'});
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(content);
    a.click();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="target">
    <input type="text" value="" onchange="updateValue(this)">
</div>
<script>
    function updateValue(a) {
    // update the input value
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The serialized DOM doesn’t represent the current value, because the `value` _property_ is the current value, whereas the `value` _attribute_ is the initial value, and DOM serialization only looks at the current attribute values. See [What is the difference between properties and attributes in HTML?](/q/6003819/4642212). You’d have to do `target.setAttribute("value", target.value);` to update it.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+innerHTML+doesn%E2%80%99t+include+input+value) of [Inner HTML with input values](/q/12126497/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in JavaScript, relation between DOM object and unparsed HTML (so to say property vs attribute) is not 2 way sync. it is one way sync. it means that when you modified DOM  objects 'value' property, your HTML in browser won't be chanced.

So you use **setAttribute** method of DOM. thats all.